# Android: Restrict friends to appear on facebook multi friend selector

Tags: android, facebook

I used this code to open a dialog and show some friends to send an invite:

```
private void sendRequestDialog() {
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

WebDialog requestsDialog = (
    new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
        Session.getActiveSession(),
        params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error != null) {
                    if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Request cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Network Error", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                    if (requestId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Request sent",  
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Request cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }   
            }

        })
        .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
}
```

This shows all my friends but I need to restrict this list... I found a param named exclude_ids but in facebook guide it says it doesnt work on mobile.

Is there any easy way for me to do this?

Tks,
Thiago

Comment: By what way, do you want to restrict the list ?

Comment: I have a list of ids. I think it would be possible to put this list as a param for RequestsDialogBuilder.

Comment: You can simply execute fql call to get desired list of friends and list them.

Comment: How I open a dialog with FQL? Can I use fql with WebDialog?

Comment: Using FQL I could bring only the users I want but doing this I´ll have to create my own multi-friends-selector with that list? or I can use some from facebook api and just pass my list?